# Add a function template in PyCharm

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

I am developing python code in pycharm

I am looking to define a skeleton of function definition in python.

What I am looking for is that each time I initiate a function definition, say:

```
def func1(arg1,arg2):
```

and press **enter**, it should automatically create the below skeleton for me to edit inside of it.

```
def func1(arg1,arg2):
    try:
        return(1)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Is that possible in PyCharm?

Comment: Do none of [these](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=add+a+function+template+in+pycharm&ie=&oe=) help?

Comment: @DavidG i could only see file level template not function level :(. i'm new to pycharm

Comment: Follow guide here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `file > settings`

Once an editor dialogue is opened, expand `Editor` and select `Live Templates` as shown in the image below.

[image]

Expand preferred option, in your case `python` here.

Click on the green plus sign at top right corner and select `Live Template`

[image: Live template selection]

After that has been done define `Abbreviation`, `Description`, and `Template Text` as shown below.

[image: Define everything]

You would see a warning just below `Template Text`, you will have to define the context where this template can be used.

See below, select all that is applicable and click `apply` and `ok`.

[image: select context]

Finally, try typing the `Abbreviation` wherever applicable and hit enter.

[image: type it]

you will see the template as below.

[image: Actual live template]

That's it. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely possible - PyCharm has a function called "Live Templates," which you can read more about [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-applying-live-templates-code-snippets.html).  Based on what you're trying to do, the code you would want to define in your "Template text" would look like:

```
def $name$(arg1,arg2):
    try:
        return(1)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        $END$
```

You'll have edit your variables (or add more than just $name$ if you want to populate more than just the name) and then, whenever you type `def`, one of the options on the menu should be your predefined function stub.

The JetBrains documentation goes into more detail in how to do this, as well as troubleshooting things (make sure you define your context as "Python"), but this should be enough to get you up and running.  Hope this helps!